# Stub pass parameter to scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

I have scope in my model which looks like:

```
scope :public, -> { another_scope.where(v_id: 1) }
```

When I stub this model in tests:

```
model.stub(:test).and_return(test)
```

it passes a value to this scope so I receive

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

How can I avoid this?
When I change it to:

```
scope :public, ->(arg) { another_scope.where(v_id: 1) }
```

it works fine, but arg is never used

It also works fine when I don't use lambda ex:

```
scope :public, another_scope.where(v_id: 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html) instead of a lambda.**

```
scope :public, proc{ another_scope.where( v_id: 1 ) }
```

lambdas are a "strict" kind of proc that require the right amount of arguments.

**Alternatively**, here's a little hack if you want to keep the 'stabby lambda' syntax (though it's not so readable, and looks oddly disturbing to me, like a miniature Eye of Sauron):

```
scope :public, ->(*){ another_scope.where( v_id: 1 ) }
```

The splat functions exactly the same way than when you use it in method signatures like `def foo( *args ); end`, except the args don't get captured in a variable.